# installing django 1.3 for appengine w/ python 2.7 needs settings.py and more

Tags: django, macos, python-2.7

How can django 1.3 or higher be installed with appengine using python27 by someone who is just starting out and not upgrading python nor django? I have read several pretty good blogs and instructions, but they don't help me especially with settings.py (is it still needed, what goes in it and where does it go, for example)?

Apparently there is rather big change in using django 1.0 and higher with python 2.7, but the help references I have found do not deal with python 2.7 and django or if they do, they talk about updating from django 0.96, but I don't remember ever dealing with settings.py, which they assume I understand.

I only want to use django with python, not have totally django app, which I understand is also possible.

I have studied several tutorials and two of the better ones even send the reader to a "working" url, that does not work. A couple of the better links are below.

noob cannot post this hyperlink: thomas.broxrost.com/2008/04/08/django-on-google-app-engine/

http://www.john-smith.me/Tag/webapp2

Btw, I am very interested in extending the shoppinglist example at the following link and wonder if it has been updated to work with python 2.7 and django 1.3.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/djangoforms

Thanks, very much,

Brian in Atlanta

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [djangoappengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine) library and probably [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel), that is a Django fork for be able to work with non relational databases.

Comment: Your answer looks like it takes a very different approach from the one suggested by appengine. I don't think I need SQL, only GQL. In your answer where is reference to system.py, for example?

Comment: I meant settings.py, of course, not system.py. "In your answer where is reference to system.py, for example?"

Comment: Well, it maybe not the best way to deal with it, but at least you will be able to work with Django 1.3 (sort of) and Python 2.7. I work with those technologies everyday on App Engine and it works fine (as fine as App Engine can work ;))

Comment: I think I should apologize for me earlier comment b/c it looks like your suggestion may be the only possibility for me now. I found [link](http://seperohacker.blogspot.com/2012/04/installing-django-nonrel-easily.html] very valuable. I left a message there and have been directly to great links by seperohacker. Thank you.